# How do I make embeddable radio autoplay?

Tags: flash

I'm embedding a flash radio player and I've changed the flashVAR to true: `<param name="FlashVars" value="autoPlay=true">`

Yet I've only gotten the player to autoplay in IE, but not other browsers. Thoughts?

---

mark's code from an answer:

```
<object
 classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
 codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0"
 width="300" height="250">
  <param name="movie" value="http://8tracks.com/mixes/145636/player_v3">
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
  <param name="FlashVars" value="autoPlay=true">
  <embed src="http://8tracks.com/mixes/145636/player_v3"
    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    width="300" height="250" allowscriptaccess="always" >
  </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: I recommend registering an account - it'll make coming back here and editing your questions/answers easier

Answer (score 0):

You are liking using an embed tag within an object tag so that it works smoothly in IE and other browsers.  When doing this, make sure you have changed the appropriate variable in *both* tags.

On another note, if you'd add your HTML, and more information about your specific problem, you'd probably get more replies.

Answer (score 0):

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="300" height="250"><param name="movie" value="http://8tracks.com/mixes/145636/player_v3"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="FlashVars" value="autoPlay=true"><embed src="http://8tracks.com/mixes/145636/player_v3" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="250" allowscriptaccess="always" ></embed></object>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You most use `embed src="http://8tracks.com/mixes/145636/player_v3?autoplay=true"` for other browsers, example:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
 codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0"
 width="300" height="250">
<param name="movie" value="http://8tracks.com/mixes/145636/player_v3">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="FlashVars" value="autoPlay=true">
<embed src="http://8tracks.com/mixes/145636/player_v3?autoplay=true"
  pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"
  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="250" allowscriptaccess="always" >
</embed>
</object>
```